# NVD3 line chart single record issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, nvd3.js

[image: Nvd3 chart]

Hi,

I am facing strange issue while using nvd3 line chart. For the single record its showing the data in the middle of the graph and for multiple data it is working perfectly. Issue with single data is its showing future dates which i relly dont want to display.

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
            var chart = nv.models.lineChart().x(function(d) {
                return d.x
            }).y(function(d) {
                return d.y
            }).color(d3.scale.category10().range())
                    .useInteractiveGuideline(true);

            chart.forceY([0,unitInterval]);

            chart.yAxis.scale().domain([ 0, 9999999 ]);

            var format = ',f';
            chart.yAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
                return nFormatter(d);
            }).axisLabel('No. Of Records');

            chart.margin({
                bottom : 50,
                left : 75
            });//set margin 

            chart.xAxis.axisLabel("Duration").tickFormat(function(d) {
                return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d));
            });

            chart.noData("Data unavailable for current selection.");

            d3.select('#recordChartDiv svg').datum(data).transition()
                    .duration(500).call(chart);

            nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
```

this is the code i am using. Can someone pls help to arrange the tick properly in case of single record?
This is working fine in another graph for multiple data. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect the graph to look like with only one data point?

You could add a domain and forceX to show the points date as a maximum like so: 
`chart.forceX([minDate, date]);
chart.xAxis.scale().domain([minDate, date]);`

see this fiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/b3fwowzz/14/